# Is this formula the calculation of covariance matrix

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

I came across this formula in a text that says $S$ is the sample covariance matrix where

$$S = \sum_{j=1}^n(\mathbf{X}_j - \bar{\mathbf{X}})(\mathbf{X}_j-\bar{\mathbf{X}})'$$.

What I am trying to figure out is whether that formula is the correct formula for a covariance matrix, or if it is, say, the sum of squares matrix around the sample mean (is that the same as the covariance matrix)?

Comment: It depends on what your symbols mean: if the necessary factor of $1/n$ (or perhaps $1/(n-1)$ is absorbed (*via* its square root) within $\mathbf X$ then this can be a correct formula for covariance, but otherwise it's not.  Please clarify.

Comment: @whuber there is no factor of 1/n (or 1/(n-1)) here (absorbed or otherwise).

Comment: That settles it, then.  You can find [many threads about covariance matrix formulas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=covariance+matrix+formula+answers%3A1+) here on CV and [many more answers that utilize them.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=covariance+matrix+formula+score%3A5+is%3Aanswer+-regression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the sample covariance matrix is:

$\mathbf{S}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{X}_i-\bar{\mathbf{X}})(\mathbf{X}_i-\bar{\mathbf{X}})^\top$